# error comparing two string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I made the following script with the following java controller.
In the controller I set an attribute of the uimodel, this attribute is an id and I convert it to be sure that is a string.
After that, in my script I take the value in a variable, then I print the type of this variable and it's a string and the value is 1.
But when I compare it with the line :

```
if (profile.toString() != "1" || profile.toString() != "2") {
    alert("pas manager");    
}
```

the alert is displayed but the id profile is equal to 1 so th alert shouldn't appear ! 
I tried with number but it's not working too

Controller Java :

```
uiModel.addAttribute(WebConstants.PROFIL_ID, user.getProfile().getId().toString());
```

JS script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 Ext.onReady(function() {
 var profile = ${profilId};
 alert(typeof profile.toString() + profile);
 alert(typeof "1" + "1");
 if (profile.toString() != "1" || profile.toString() != "2") {
     alert("pas manager");
     App.removeOption(Ext.getElementById("site.country.zone.region.code"));
     App.populateTargetListForWorkflow("", Ext.getElementById("site.country.zone.region.code"), "region"); 
}
else {
    alert("manager");
    Ext.getElementById("site.country.zone.region.code").options[0].value = "EUATEST";
}
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have a solution to correct this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic problem.

```
if (a != "1" || a != "2") {
```

is always verified, whatever the value of `a`, because `a` can't be equal to `1` and `2` at the same time.

You seem to want

```
if (profile.toString() != "1" && profile.toString() != "2") {
```

Comment: Thank you @dystroy, I think I'm really tired to make an error like that ^^

Answer (score -3):

If you alert showing profile id is '1' then change the code as below.

here i change the != to !==. For more information please **[Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Ext.onReady(function() {
     var profile = ${profilId};
     alert(typeof profile.toString() + profile);
     alert(typeof "1" + "1");
     if (profile.toString() !== "1" || profile.toString() !== "2") {
         alert("pas manager");
         App.removeOption(Ext.getElementById("site.country.zone.region.code"));
         App.populateTargetListForWorkflow("", Ext.getElementById("site.country.zone.region.code"), "region"); 
    }
    else {
        alert("manager");
        Ext.getElementById("site.country.zone.region.code").options[0].value = "EUATEST";
    }
    });
    </script>
```